Sharing expo debug builds for Firebase App Distribution
We have an Expo app and want to use Firebase App Distribution internally for our testers to quickly validate stuff.
However, when we run ./gradlew assembleDebug and share an APK this also has the bundler into it which requires a development server to be running to open the APK.
How can we share debug builds without the bundler running? We tried ./gradlew assembleRelease but this takes a lot a time to build.
I'm aware of Expo Build, but I'm looking for a solution where I can do it locally.

If you have a MacOS system, you can run local builds with eas.
For example
It seems to me you want to create a preview build for Android devices, then run the following command. The --local flag makes it possible to build the .APK file locally on your system.

However, this will only work on MacOS

$   eas build --profile preview --platform android --local

There is another option for building on Windows but I personally have no experience with it.

On Windows, you can use WSL for local EAS Builds. However, we do not officially test against this platform and do not support Windows for local builds (macOS and Linux are supported).


Documentation


If you want to follow standard React Native build process. Use Expo prebuild. Just run expo prebuild --release-channel dev. That will generate prebuilt APK or IPA that doesn't require a development server.
If you want faster build process. You can create a custom build variant that uses the release configuration but with development setting.
in your android/app/build.gradle, add new build type:
android {
  buildTypes {
    devRelease {
      initWith release
      matchingFallbacks = ['release']
      signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

Then you can build with ./gradlew assembleDevRelease
